# JSTree loading lazy loading not working for my resource url but is for sample url

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I am loading data as per an example I found using the code below.  It allows me to specify a url and using the sample's url https://www.jstree.com/fiddle/?lazy I get a working tree on my page.  This url returns a json of:

> [{"id":1,"text":"Root node","children":[{"id":2,"text":"Child node
> 1","children":true},{"id":3,"text":"Child node 2"}]}]

I have created my own url which returns exactly the same json.  My problem is that using my url it delivers a single tree node with my json string as the name of the node as per my attached image.  As far as I can see both urls are returning the same json string and is just raw text but I don't understand why it is interpreting mine incorrectly.  Could anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
    $(function() {
      $('#jstree').jstree({
        'core' : {
          'data' : {
            "url" : "/_content/data/table/companytree.aspx/?lazy",
            "data" : function (node) {
              return { "id" : node.id };
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

**apologies I added the wrong code snippet**

The first image is using the sample url and the second is using mine..

[image: working tree:]

[image: Error tree]

Comment: I don't know if this helps but when I call both urls in my browser, the jstree url is recognised as json and the browser opens a plugin which allows you to show raw/json.  With my urll however it does not do this.  Hinting that it is not json or does not recognise it as such but both strings are identical and are valid json.

Comment: So I run both urls in https://jsonparser.org/ load url option and as suspected my url does NOT parse.  So even though both json strings are identical in my browser results there is something I am missing to identify the string as json..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only thing I can think of, while server is returning the data it need to have the response header. Please check this, I think thats the issue, rest looks good to me.

```
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

You can also try once, adding the contentType, I have not used this structure exactly, but generally this will tell that the return type is json incase thats not in header.

```
$(function() {
      $('#jstree').jstree({
        'core' : {
          'data' : {
            "url" : "/_content/data/table/companytree.aspx/?lazy",
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "data" : function (node) {
              return { "id" : node.id };
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Hi there :)..  So I tried that already with no luck this morning.  But just after I put on the bounty I tried something different and instead of returning the JSON as text on a page for the tree to then devour I returned the json in a response from my aspx page.  Of course that worked.  Only spent a few weeks trying to get the above to work as the demo does.  The only thing I missed that you added is the charset in your contentType..  I am going to see if that makes any difference and will report back.

Comment: Hi again, so no is didn't work with your additional text.  I feel it should have done though.  It doesn't make sense to me why it didn't.  But I have it now.  Thank you for your comment and advice :)

Comment: no problem ! happy you could make it work ! Generally all jstree need to know is the ajax is returning a json, if the content-type is in the header that will work, whatever way you can do that.

Comment: I see your answer, so you did the option 1 I have suggested. thats great !

Comment: Hi, your suggestion didn't work even though it should have worked.  I have already tried your suggestion before submitting the extra bounty.  I now send the data using the content type via http response from my aspx page and not via the jquery call for the data.

Comment: Ah..  I now see what you said in your option 1.  Sorry I only saw option 2 :):):)..

Comment: Happy to give the points to you, but I didn't do the below based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added this code to my aspx code which fetches the data to post back to the page..  Instead of posting the json to the page I return a http response..  It works for me but would love to know why the demo approach didn't.  Content type seems the likely culprit bit I don't know.

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8

        Dim bom As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()
        Response.BinaryWrite(bom)
        Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PageDataRecords))
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
```